# Rails Temporary Tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, temp-tables

Quick question in regards to temp tables in Rails.

I have an app where users upload data via a CSV.

I would like to validate the data against data in the database as a first step for validation, so I want to import the data into a temp table first. Once I am done validating the data (which will essentially be just joining the temp table to the 'real' table) I will destroy the temp.

I saw this: 
http://richtextblog.blogspot.com/2007/09/mysql-temporary-tables-and-rails.html

But I have no idea where I would execute that and/or how you would be able to access the table, like I would an AR object.

Comment: Hi G! did u find a solution for this issue? looking for the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

If the CSV file is complex and there won't be very frequent uploads, I would simply use normal model and mark the unverified data as unverified. If user found it okay and confirm, the it got verified, otherwise it got destroyed. Much simpler.

Comment: This won't work because I am doing the verification to prevent duplicate records. But I do appreciate the answer.